# Bad Gateway when configuring nginx with. Django app container and Gunicorn

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to deploy a Django app on a VM with  Nginx installed on the VM as a web server.

but I'm getting " 502 Bad gateway" I believe it's a network issue I think Nginx can't access the docker container! however, when I use the same configuration in an Nginx container it worked perfectly with the Django app but I need to use the installed one not the one with docker.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  web:
    image: ngrorra/newsapp:1.0.2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: django-static
        target: /code/static
      - type: volume
        source: django-media
        target: /code/media
    environment:
      - "DEBUG_MODE=False"
      - "DB_HOST=…”
      - "DB_PORT=5432"
      - "DB_NAME=db_1”
      - "DB_USERNAME=username1111"
volumes:
  django-static:
  django-media:
```

And this is my nginx.conf file:

```
upstream web_app {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen   80;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /code/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /code/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web_app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }
    #For favicon
    location  /favicon.ico {
        alias /code/assets/favicon.ico;
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /code/templates/;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what is the issue?
Thank you!

Comment: If nginx is not being run with docker-compose you can’t use the web service name as the host in upstream, this is only possible when both apps are running in containers in same docker-compose network. Use localhost instead

Comment: I replace it with localhost but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, using "web" as host name will not work, you could try localhost or the docker ip (you can get it using ifconfig in Ubuntu, for example).

For the network issue, I think you could create a new docker external network using [docker network create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) and adding to your "network" [definition inside compose] (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network). Another possibility is to use the [host as network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode)

When I run docker aplications with Nginx, usualy I create first an external docker network with defined IP (using some docker network IP - usualy 172.x.x.x), then add a Nginx container to my docker-compose.yaml and my server inside nginx.conf is something like this:

```
upstream web_app {
    server 172.x.x.x:8000;
  }
.
.
.
```

It works without problems. Hope this can help you.

Comment: but how can I attach Nginx to the external network if it's not a docker container?

Comment: Good question, I never tried using a Nginx in host...Maybe using host as network then for your compose? Maybe in this case localhost will work. As I said, usually I have nginx inside the compose so the docker external network works fine.